# 5 columns but 6 values given

Tags: sql

[image][Code done in SQL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjeNg.png)

Confused why this error is appearing when there are 6 columns and 6 values listed. I am just learning SQL.

Comment: It's preferably to post code rather than pictures of code. I'm not familiar with sqlite, but it may be preventing you from inserting  a value into the primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

You should list the columns explicitly:

```
insert into takehome_2 (ProductId, ProductName, SupplierId, CategoryId, UnitId, Price)
   values (. . . );
```

This is a good habit in general.  In this case, SQLite might just tell you which column is unexpected.

My best guess is that something is fishy with the table name, so the table referenced for the `insert` is not the same as the table that has just been created.

Answer (score 0):

**OperationalError**

Exception raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the data source name is not found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation error occurred during processing, etc.

This error is a DBAPI Error and originates from the database driver (DBAPI), not SQLAlchemy itself.

The OperationalError is the most common (but not the only) error class used by drivers in the context of the database connection being dropped, or not being able to connect to the database. For tips on how to deal with this, see the section Dealing with Disconnects.